# Delete everything but alphnumeric characters and spaces

Tags: string-manipulation

This should have been asked here, but apparently it hasn't. How to delete everything from a string except alphanumeric characters and spaces? For example,

```
str = "This is, my string number 5!"
```

I want it to be `"This is my string number 5"`

Comment: `StringReplace["This is, my string number 5!", Except[LetterCharacter | DigitCharacter | " "] -> ""]` gives the output you want (but doesn't have special characters).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use `RegularExpression`

```
str = "This is, my string number 5!";
reg = RegularExpression["[A-Za-z0-9 ]"];
StringJoin[StringCases[str, reg]] // InputForm
```

gives

```
"This is my string number 5"
```

The " " is for any space, and `A-Za-z0-9` stuff is for alpha numeric.

Answer (score 5):

```
str = "This is, my string number 5!"
StringJoin@
 StringCases[str
  , (DigitCharacter | LetterCharacter | WhitespaceCharacter)
  ]
```

---

```
StringDelete[str, PunctuationCharacter]
```

---

Result:

> "This is my string number 5"